# Binding Dependency Property to View Model

Tags: wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I have two user controls defined as follows:

**User Control 1**

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestBindings.UserControlOne"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestBindings">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:UserControlOneViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>


    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProperty}"/>
        <local:UserControlTwo PropertyTwo="{Binding DataContext.MyProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
    </StackPanel>   


</UserControl>
```

Code Behind

```
    public partial class UserControlOne : UserControl
       {
          public UserControlOne()
          {
             InitializeComponent();
          }
       }
```

**User Control 2**

XAML

```
    <UserControl x:Class="TestBindings.UserControlTwo"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestBindings">

        <UserControl.DataContext>
            <local:UserControlTwoViewModel/>
        </UserControl.DataContext>

        <TextBlock Name="TextBlock" Text="{Binding PropertyTwo}"/>

    </UserControl>
```

Code Behind

```
public partial class UserControlTwo : UserControl
   {
      public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyTwoProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("PropertyTwo", typeof (string), typeof (UserControlTwo),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("Default", OnPropertyTwoChanged));

      public UserControlTwo()
      {
         InitializeComponent();

         var propertyTwoBinding = new Binding("PropertyTwo") {Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay};
         SetBinding(PropertyTwoProperty, propertyTwoBinding);
      }

      public string PropertyTwo
      {
         get { return (string) GetValue(PropertyTwoProperty); }
         set { SetValue(PropertyTwoProperty, value); }
      }

      private static void OnPropertyTwoChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
         var userControlTwo = (UserControlTwo) d;
         userControlTwo.PropertyTwo = (string) e.NewValue;
      }
   }
```

In UserControlTwo's constructor I bind the dependency property PropertyTwoProperty to a property in the associated ViewModel. I ultimately want to bind this to a property in the ViewModel of UserControlOne, hence UserControlOne xaml

```
<local:UserControlTwo PropertyTwo="{Binding DataContext.MyProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
```

However this never seems to get set. Any ideas where I may be going wrong?

Comment: I don't get it. If you want to bind `UserControlTwo.PropertyTwo` to `MyProperty` of the DataContext in UserControlOne, everything you need to do is `<local:UserControlTwo PropertyTwo="{Binding MyProperty}"/>`. There is no need to call SetBinding in the constructor of UserControlTwo.

Comment: I dont think you need even the relative source, simply PropertyTwo="{Binding MyProperty} should do. You already got the datacontext, no need to specify it

Comment: Moreover, the OnPropertyTwoChanged callback doesn't make sense. It sets `PropertyTwo` (again) to the value it just got (that's why the PropertyChanged was called).

Comment: @Clemens I want to do some view logic for UserControlTwo in UserControlTwo's ViewModel, therefore how do I set the binding in xaml but get hold of that property in UserControlTwo's ViewModel

Comment: Simply put, how do you "connect" the dependency property of a custom control to a property in its ViewModel

Comment: Why do you need to setbinding in UserControlTwo constructor? You are already doing that in the xaml?

Comment: @Krishna I may be doing it wrong. I want to know how to bind to a property in xaml, but access that property in a ViewModel for that UserControl

Comment: @JamesB remove the setbinding from the constructor and in your xaml remove the relativesource and simply usePropertyTwo="{Binding MyProperty,Mode=TwoWay}" let me know if it works for you

Comment: Wait I think I understood what you are trying to do. Let me post an answer

Comment: This is the wrong approach. UserControlTwo should not have its own "local" view model instance, when it is supposed to have its properties bound "externally". That's confusing.

Comment: @Clemens Probably why I'm getting confused. But I want to be able to re-use the control and its logic. How can i define a user control with logic if not with its own ViewModel?

Comment: Not sure which logic we are talking about here, but it could probably be implemented in the control's code-behind.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to pass a property from the datacontext of UserControlOne to a DependencyProperty in UserControlTwo.

In that case you use the below approach and also remove the setbinding in the code in your UserControl2 Constructor. Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

```
    <UserControl x:Class="TestBindings.UserControlOne"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="userControl"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestBindings">

        <UserControl.DataContext>
            <local:UserControlOneViewModel/>
        </UserControl.DataContext>


        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProperty}"/>
            <local:UserControlTwo PropertyTwo="{Binding DataContext.MyProperty, ElementName=userControl,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StackPanel>   


    </UserControl>
```

Comment: Yes, but I also need to access the DependencyProperty of UserControlTwo in UserControlTwo's ViewModel

Comment: @JamesB if you know what viewmodel it is, then in your OnPropertyTwoChanged method, cast the datacontext as the VM and update its property.

Comment: how do i get the data context in a static method?

Comment: You can access it by var vm = userControlTwo.DataContext as VM; and then you can do vm.YourProperty = e.NewValue.ToString();